# How to use AddExternalLogin method from WebAPI template

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

I use Web API template. My target is REST service with Facebook, Twitter, and Google registration and authorization.

I can create account using social networks, but can't add another social network login to existing account.

Specifically, the problem is occurring in this method:

```
// POST api/Account/AddExternalLogin
[Route("AddExternalLogin")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddExternalLogin(AddExternalLoginBindingModel model)
```

And even more specifically, the value returned from this call is `null`,

```
 AuthenticationTicket ticket = AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(model.ExternalAccessToken);
```

Which explicitly causes the API to return `BadRequest("External login failure.");`.

The only member in `AddExternalLoginBindingModel` is `ExternalAccessToken`, which I'm filling with a social network access token.

How do I add an external login to an existing account? What information should I send to the `AddExternalLogin` method?

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if I'm doing something conceptually wrong, but I just solved this by avoiding using AccessTokenFormat;
Basically is the same flow as when you login at the first time. But when you get the auth token, then you must set Authorization header ("Bearer " +) and call the adjusted api bellow:

```cs
[OverrideAuthentication]
[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]
[Route("AddExternalLogin")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddExternalLogin() {
    var info = await Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

    if (info == null) {
        return InternalServerError();
    }

    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), new UserLoginInfo(info.Login.LoginProvider, info.Login.ProviderKey));

    Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    if (!result.Succeeded) {
        return GetErrorResult(result);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same as you. so is this the correct flow ?
1) SignUp the new user
2) Login with the new user and get the asp.net identity access token
3) with the access token call the AddExternalLogin and send the facebook token in the binding contract

Comment: @JoseManuelOjeda As far I remember you're right (I don't have the code anymore). Login the user > do external login > get access token > call AddExternalLogin api with Authorization header = Bearer <access_token>